# What kind of security does a website without user login functionality need?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, xss, sql-injection

So I'm googling this question and can't really find any clear examples since almost all related stories are about websites with user log-in's etc.

so my scenario is as follows, asp.net MVC3 website, no user login, nothing.
I do have some forms on there though, contact and some calculation features.

I use Nhibernate, and have my Smtp server credentials in the code itself, not in the web.config. I also have a custom error page and post methods have the [HttpPost] attribute.

As a final feature I have an AJAX/json get method that gets a list of titles.(this controller method has the [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)] attribute).

Am I missing some big security holes here(sql injection, cross site scripting)?

Thanks guys

Comment: The presence of user logins really doesn't make much difference at all to the potential security vulnerabilites of a website. Any time you process any input from the user --whether logged in or not-- you are at risk of them acting maliciously, so that includes all URLs, query string data, form post data, cookies, http headers etc. Start with the top ten as Tony suggests and continue to read around OWASP to learn more about webapp vulnerabilities and how to avoid them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd still be vulnerable to DDoS and DoS attacks, and if you don't https then you'll be vulnerable to MiM attacks.

Though NHibernate and ASP.NET MVC3 should cover most of your tracks for you. I would be very suprised if they didn't have proper form validation client and server-side and that the db inputs aren't made sanitised.

How do you manage your data? - Do you have a login just for admin?

If so, make you protect it, and for added measure, don't put it on `/login/` or `/admin/`!

Comment: I'm still working on the admin panel, for now, the only way to update data is a direct connection with the database. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Using a framework does not automatically protect you from typical common vulnerabilities. I've seen plenty of people write SQL in NHibernate - it only takes one injectable query to compromise the entire database. As for MVC - that protects you from pretty much nothing. These things aren't magic pills; you still need to understand the issues and know how to protect against them. As for /login /admin etc. - whilst it is perfectly sound advice, that is *obscurity*, not *security*

Comment: i popped you back up as someone had voted you down for what i can only presume was your wild initial sentence. i'd re-evaluate that if you wanna stay on an even keel here

Answer (score 2):

Start here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

Answer (score 0):

The only types of attacks you would not be vulnerable to would be any type of Authentication Bypass or Privilege Escalation. The rest of the OWASP Top 10 (and SANS top 25 for that matter http://www.sans.org/top25-software-errors/) would still be applicable.

Despite the typical SQL Injection and XSS vulnerabilities, there are a number of other "injection" type vulnerabilites, such as OS Command Injection and Path Traversals that you should be aware of. Don't forget you should also be aware of securing your hosting environment (hardening the web server, applicaiton server, and the server itself).